# Comment formatting trial area feature request

Tags: feature-request

I am having a hard time understanding the mini markdown editing of the comments.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) guide about comment formatting is incomplete if new users can't experiment with formatting comments without writing a real comment. Either please show the preview in comments as well or provide us with some sort of "Try now" area [there](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) .

If there is already some kind of provision for trying out mini-markdown formatting without writing an actual comment, please tell me.

Comment: Despite [the sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122) on meta, an actual comment preview would probably be a nice feature.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the StackExchange [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122) question:

> You can use this question as a formatting sandbox. You can
>
> - edit this question itself (Community Wiki questions such as this one require 100 reputation to edit)
> - post answers to this question (Since this question is protected, this requires earning 10 reputation on this site)
> - post comments to this question or its answers
> - test suspected bugs with the editor

Comment: That's pretty cool. Unfortunately, I wouldn't have known it existed had I not  found this question in the "Hot Meta Posts"sidebar. It doesn't seem to be referenced in either the main `editing-help` or `editing-help#comment-formatting` pages.

Comment: @Hephaestus That's why the OP has made a feature request ;)

Comment: Indeed. That's also why I upvoted his feature request. ;-)